# Will this button click event do what it needs to do?

Tags: c#, events, button, click, paint

I have a small beginners problem, I have a buttonclick event and I want the event to initialize a paint event in the form1_paint. I have a class Oversteekplaats with 2 paint events, one called teken1 and the other called teken2. In Form1_paint teken1 is already initialized. And through a boolean that is changed when u click Button1 I want it to repaint form1_paint.

code:

```
    public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Opdracht 1
    rood = new FietsLamp(Color.Red, 10, 10, 60);
    oranje = new VoetgangerLamp(Color.Orange, 120, 10, 60);
    rood.Status = LampStatus.Aan;
    oranje.Status = LampStatus.Aan;

    // Opdracht 2
    stoplicht = new Stoplicht(10, 120, 130, 280);

    // Opdracht 3
    voetgangerlicht = new VoetgangerStoplicht(150, 120, 130, 195);
    fietslicht = new FietsStoplicht(290, 120, 130, 195);

    // Opdracht 5 (teken oversteekplaats en zebrapad voor voetganger)
    oversteekplaats1 = new Oversteekplaats(650, 10, 200, 200);
    oversteekplaats2 = new Oversteekplaats(650, 210, 200, 200);
    oversteekplaats3 = new Oversteekplaats(650, 410, 200, 200);
    oversteekplaats4 = new Oversteekplaats(450, 210, 200, 200);
    oversteekplaats5 = new Oversteekplaats(850, 210, 200, 200);
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (voetganger == false) 
    { 
        voetganger = true; 
    }
    if (voetganger == true) 
    { 
        voetganger = false;
    }

}

public void Form1_Paint(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Opdracht 1 graphics
    rood.Teken(e.Graphics);
    oranje.Teken(e.Graphics);

    // Opdracht 2 graphics
    stoplicht.Teken(e.Graphics);

    // Opdracht 3 graphics
    voetgangerlicht.Teken(e.Graphics);
    fietslicht.Teken(e.Graphics);

    // Opdracht 5 graphics
    oversteekplaats1.Teken1(e.Graphics);
    oversteekplaats2.Teken1(e.Graphics);
    oversteekplaats3.Teken1(e.Graphics);
    oversteekplaats4.Teken1(e.Graphics);
    oversteekplaats5.Teken1(e.Graphics);

    if (voetganger == true)
    {
    oversteekplaats4.Teken2(e.Graphics, 120);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, have you tried to run this code to see if it does what you want?

Comment: all your button click does is flip the boolean value

Comment: Use `Form1.Invalidate()` to repaint. I think that's what you want.

Comment: What error do you get when you try it ? You shouldn't ask if something will work. Just try it on your own that is part or programming.

Comment: This question is an EXACT copy of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709558/will-this-button-click-event-work

Comment: @LokiSinclair Yet you didn't vote/flag to close either question...

Comment: @Servy - Actually I tried, but at the time, neither one had upvotes or accepted answers and it wouldn't allow me to.

Comment: @LokiSinclair Fair enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to refresh drawings after button's click just call `Invalidate()`.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (voetganger == false) 
    { 
        voetganger = true; 
    }
    else if (voetganger == true) 
    { 
        voetganger = false;
    }

    this.Invalidate();
}
```

And for being a little thoughtful, I'll write that condition this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    voetganger = !(voetganger);
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: In your first example, `voetganger` will always be false upon exiting the method. The second `if` statement should be an `else if`.